# Java certification: "& can have integral as well as boolean operands"

Tags: java

I'm reading a book of Hanumant Deshmukh preparing OCAJP, and I don't understand this:

> & can have integral as well as boolean operands

Why is this true?

---

**Edit 01.02.2019**

Nice post about bitwise operations: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bitwise-operators

Comment: Because it can? I've just written `boolean a = true & true;` and it compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when used on integral types, it represents/means a `bitwise and` operation. This is a bitwise operation.

For more details see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise **&** operator works with integral operands like **AND** operator in boolean logic.

Example: 15 & 7 = 7, is same to: 1111 AND 0111 = 0111

This should help:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.co/2013/03/bitwise-and-bitshift-operators-in-java-and-or-xor-left-right-shift-example-tutorial.html